# Fetching mysql error from datamapper

Tags: mysql, ruby, sinatra, datamapper

Is there anyway to fetch the mysql error in datamapper (I am using Sinatra)

```
@params = {"product"=>"client", "os"=>"windows", "architecture"=>"32", "version"=>""}
@a = Package.new(@params)
@a.save
```

`@a.save` returns me false, because version cannot be null. But How can I retrieve this error message (that mysql must have returned saying version can not be null)?

Answer (score -1):

[DataMapper:](http://datamapper.org/docs/validations.html) *If your validators find errors in your model, they will populate the Validate::ValidationErrors object that is available through each of your models via calls to your model's errors method.*

```
if @a.save
  #Record saved 
else 
  @a.errors.each do |e|
    puts e
  end
end
```

Comment: Not sure, but it did not work :( I am using dm-is-reflective.